# how can i loop from last item to first item in Angular2

Tags: angular, ngfor

I simply want to display these list of items starting from the last to the first, and I have no Idea how to go about it.

```
<div ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">{{item}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just simply reversing the input?

```
<div ngFor="let item of items.slice().reverse(); let i=index">{{item}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can use js' functions inside view but let's try.

`<div *ngFor="let item of items.reverse(); let i=index">{{item}}</div>`